# laravel - InvalidArgumentException view [pages.home] not found

Tags: php, laravel

i've been stumped by thhis one for a couple of days now. I get this error when i try loading the main page, I get the error in the title. I've asked this question [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/view-not-found-1) and tried putting dd() at the top of the page as well as running php artisan route:clear as well as other commands hoping I can get the home page to load. The funny thing is I can load the user login function no problem.

Here's my routes file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.home');
});



Route::auth();
```

View Structure:

[image]

Comment: Show us your view directory structure. Do you have a file name `/resources/views/pages/home.blade.php`? A common issue is to forget the *blade* portion of the filename or the *php* extension.

Comment: try `Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('pages.home');
});` and tell me the result

Comment: @xhulio That is literally the code that he posted. The issue is it cannot find the view. I suspect it is a file naming or directory structure issue.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I had the same problem few days ago. It didn't get the view from the `/` route but it worked with `/home`

Comment: Here's screenshot of my directory structurehttps://postimg.org/image/7pv5qu23r/

Comment: @xhuilo, I changed the code to what you suggested, and now i get a `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:` error upon opening /home

Comment: @TomMorison Try `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @z3r0ck, i've tried that command from my VM many times, still no luck. I'm being driven crazy with this error. i'm going to take a shot in the dark and reset my whole computer and see if it does anything.

Comment: As it turns out, I don't see the pages directory in Mac OS X's finder. I guess for some reason the files are not being stored there for some reason. I'll see what i can do to get the OS to pick up my files.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. I didnt notice this before, but my project in PhpStorm was being saved to a directory outside my VM. i apologize for not figuring this out earlier.